# jmeter - my regex doesn't work. Tried to get something between 2 strings in response

Tags: regex, testing, jmeter, stress-testing

I've got this kind of response.

`</api/sale/mailboxApplications/confirm-email?verificationCode=SPTp%2FMl6Dbmqn3%2BlN0nsIfBIqmAN16Tc%2F4Hy30VIjb50US%2FRHRlzoKFRg4JjFBxeHmpecJCaiuZwtUCtVL3ELQDfw2USXHQt6Nmx87KUSzepmhlWvcXLgwLqL0vYR2Py4%2B6Fu9TIijAPrWbxPJ%2F9eelmqfzGrtxbd8Vu9u9LcrI%3D&amp;applicationId=3c77be27-98bd-4fac-bbf8-cfa201ce1a24`

or

`/api/sale/mailboxApplications/confirm-email?verificationCode=%2B1YDDRKZUi7D5nMsArlhnn6eOPtIp6aWM%2BVv6fg8OjzcBcPQI5bAQq3pHuJq8O7T0LmRrzfcwrd71VfZ2VCHVUOSGCaSa1np6XYQ0sswIPBFzepUMFi%2FynWRvrNhgA0fhvsC56nNArhYPcnghsTnRyUod%2BiS6u6CDTlYvmqzKsc%3D&amp;applicationId=733f125b-61bd-4876-aded-ed95f02da4c4 </pre>`

My problem is that I can't get "verificationCode" from this response, which is between "verificationCode=" and "&amp"

I tried this kind of regex but none of them worked:
`(?<=verificationCode=)(.*\n?)(?=&amp)`
`(?<=verificationCode=).*?(?=&amp)`
`(?<=verificationCode=)(.+)(?=&amp)`
`(?<=verificationCode=)(.*)(?=&amp)`

Every time, jmeter returns "0" as a default value.

I have checked every of these regexes in https://regex101.com/ and they work well up there
What I have missed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.
I put `verificationCode=(?s)(.*)&amp`
and set group number as $1$

Works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get something between 2 strings just go for the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), all you need to do is to provide "left" and "right" boundary and it will get everything in-between

[image]

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

If you're still looking for a [regular expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) it would be something like:

```
verificationCode=(.+?)&amp
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, there's no need to capture the value since you are utilizing the *positive look-around* syntax.

For the example, the  following *"match"* will return the text only within the two values.

```
(?<=verificationCode=).+(?=&amp;)
```

If you do plan on capturing, remove the *look-around* syntax, as this will double the amount of steps to complete, for no reason.

```
verificationCode=(.+)&amp;
```